# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):56

Tags: jquery, laravel

siempre tengo problemas en las instalaciones de jquery con laravel..

Mi fichero **webpack.mix.js**:

```
mix.autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
        'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js': ['Popper']
     })
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

**app.js**

```
...
require('./bootstrap');

// Register $ global var for jQuery
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

window.Vue = require('vue').default;
...
```

mi vista principal tiene estos imports:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Para probar que funciones jquery me he creado esto en la vista principal:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        alert('hola mundi');
    });
</script>
```

Pero la consola me sigue sin reconocer el jquery:

Consola:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):56
```

He instalado jquery con : `npm install jquery`

Answer (score 0):

Justo a cabo de encontrar que en la importación de `app.js` si quitas el atributo `defer` funciona.

Tenia esto:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Y lo he cambiado por esto:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```

Y funciona.